# Using Options Pattern for settings .NET Core app not working; settings file always has null properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I have a straight-forward .NET 6 app using full Program and Startup classes (nothing top-level). I have the following segment in Startup:

```cs
IConfigurationSection oauthSection = Configuration.GetSection("OAuth");
services.Configure<OAuthSettings>(oauthSection);
var oauthSettings = oauthSection.Get<OAuthSettings>();
```

This is OAuthSettings:

```cs
public class OAuthSettings
{
    public OAuthSettings()
    {
        CorsAllowedOrigins = new List<string>();
    }

    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

    public string DefaultSchema { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> CorsAllowedOrigins { get; set; }
}
```

I'm injecting the `IOptions<OAuthSettings>` object in another class from an adjacent library (but still part of the DI container), like the below:

```cs
private readonly IOptions<OAuthSettings> _oAuthOptions;

public IdentityServerDataProtectionDbContext(
    DbContextOptions<IdentityServerDataProtectionDbContext> options,
    IOptions<OAuthSettings> oAuthOptions)
    : base(options)
{
    _oAuthOptions = oAuthOptions;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(_oAuthOptions.Value.DefaultSchema);
}
```

However, every single time I try to call `_oAuthOptions.Value`, all of the properties are null, and the implementation is of [`UnnamedOptionsManager`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Options/UnnamedOptionsManager.cs). This is happening despite the fact that `oauthSettings` in the first snippet resolves the settings just fine, meaning it isn't a problem with deserialization.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Use `IOptionsSnapshot<>` or `IOptionsMonitor<>` instead.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#options-interfaces)

This took me way too many hours to figure out, so I wanted to answer my own question here to hopefully prevent someone else the pain.

The documentation for the various Options interfaces explains the issue better than I could (**emphasis** mine):

> IOptions:
>
> - **Does not support:**
>
>   - **Reading of configuration data after the app has started.**
>   - Named options
> - **Is registered as a Singleton** and can be injected into any service lifetime.
>
> IOptionsSnapshot:
>
> - Is useful in scenarios where options should be recomputed on every injection resolution, in scoped or transient lifetimes. For more information, see Use IOptionsSnapshot to read updated data.
> - **Is registered as Scoped** and therefore cannot be injected into a Singleton service.
> - Supports named options
>
> IOptionsMonitor:
>
> - Is used to retrieve options and manage options notifications for TOptions instances.
> - Is registered as a Singleton and can be injected into any service lifetime.
> - Supports:
>
>   - Change notifications
>   - Named options
>   - **Reloadable configuration**
>   - Selective options invalidation (IOptionsMonitorCache)